# How to compare two values from different foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is My codes,

My question is if `$company_id` from foreach one equal to `$Company_id` from foreach two then `echo company_name`.

```
$ids = array();
$x = array();
$a = array();

foreach($companieslist as $keys=>$company) {
    $x[$company->company_id] = [
        'id' => $company->company_id,
        'name' => $company->company_name
    ];
}
$entry = $a[$id];

foreach($uploads as $keys=>$general){
    $ids[] = $general->Contract_Id;
    $c_id = $general->Company_id;
    ....
```

Comment: Please explain with sample input and expected output.

Comment: i have a company table and contracts table (with company_id as foreign key) so, i want to compare those two tables if company_id equal to company_id (from contract table) then display its name (from company table)

Comment: Use JOIN in query `SELECT * FROM company as c Join contract as ct on ct.id = c.company_id`

Comment: put second foreach loop into the first one, i.e. you need 2 nested loops

Answer (score 0):

Just talking from the performance side, what you should do is extract the company ids from the second batch to an array first, like this

```
$companies = array();
foreach ( $uploads as $keys => $general ) {
    array_push( $companies, $general->Company_id );
}
```

Now, in the first foreach loop, you can just check if the company id exists in this $companies array, and then decide what to do

```
foreach($companieslist as $keys=>$company){
    if(in_array($company->company_id,$companies)){
        echo "Found {$company->company_id}<br/>\n";
    }
}
```